# How to install Scrapy Docker Container on Amazon Linux 2 AMI EC2

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, scrapy

Trying to create a docker container which would run scrapy spiders. I haven't seen any clear examples of how it is done.

I've tried multiple changes in the Dockerfile, yet I'm still doing something wrong. Can anyone assist?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux
COPY . /app
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install python3
RUN yum -y install python3-pip
RUN yum install python-devel -y
RUN yum install gcc gcc-devel -y
RUN yum install libxml2 libxml2-devel -y
RUN yum install libxslt libxslt-devel -y
RUN yum install openssl openssl-devel -y
RUN yum install libffi libffi-devel -y
RUN pip3 install lxml
RUN pip3 install scrapy
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/app/spiders/start.py"]
```

This is what the terminal gives as error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRC7D.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not docker, it is python error.
you installing `python-devel` but using python3
so you need to replace string with `python devel`
to `RUN yum install python3-devel -y`

Comment: I have no your `requirements.txt` so it is failing on `RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt` step for me. but your issue is passed.